# Passing event to the parent form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events

I have a little problem here. I'm trying to transfer/pass/raise the events of an owned form to his parent. Lets look at my example:

Lets say i have a form that initialize a CustomPanel (simply a class that inherits from System.Windows.Forms.Panel). It also have an event handler (it could be an other event, not necessarily a click event):

```
Public Sub New()
    Me.Size = New Size(1000,1000)

    Dim pnl1 As New CustomPanel()
    pnl1.Location = New Point(0,0)
    pnl1.size = New Size(100,100)
    Me.Controls.Add(pnl1)
End Sub

Private Sub form1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Click
    MsgBox("I got it!")
End Sub
```

I did something similar and when I clicked on the CustomPanel (pnl1) the parent container (form1) did not receive a click event ... which is understandable. I tried to look in the properties of the CustomPanel (pnl1) if i could find something interesting like "click through" or "raise event to parent" (I was desperate here) but without success. I said alright, I will handle the events that I need to pass to parent in the CustomPanel class but I cant find a solution here neither:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class CustomPanel
    Inherits Panel

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Private Sub CustomPanel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Click
        'What to put here?
        'Me.Parent.?
    End Sub

End Class
```

I just want to know if its possible to throw/raise/pass events to the parent. One thing is sure, its that i shouldn't have to and i cannot add anything else to the parent form. The reason is simple, i could have over 100 controls in this parent form and they could be added dynamically. And on top of that, these controls could also have their own controls inside! So i could have something like:

```
pnl99 call parent click -> pnl98 call parent click -> ... until the parent of the control really handle the click event ... -> form1 perform click event
```

Maybe its hard to understand but if you can help me I would appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Using a custom event, that the form owning the panel subscribes to. [Raise Event](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=vb.net%20raiseevent&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Ffwd3bwed.aspx&ei=BWPxUpTGCM7lygH8yYDIDA&usg=AFQjCNF2katyWZE4KsNlWxhu3QO8DXPBbw&sig2=vV9MpYlK6_klq8ap3CAmSw)

```
Public Sub New()
 Me.Size = New Size(1000,1000)

 Dim pnl1 As New CustomPanel()
 pnl1.Location = New Point(0,0)
 pnl1.size = New Size(100,100)
 Addhandler pnl1.MyClickEvent, AddressOf pl_Click
 Me.Controls.Add(pnl1)
End Sub

Private Sub pl_Click()
 MsgBox("I got it!")
End Sub
```

Custom panel:

```
Public Class CustomPanel
 Inherits Panel
 Public Event MyClickEvent

 Private Sub CustomPanel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Click
   RaiseEvent MyClickEvent()
 End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I never used RaiseEvent, could you please specify or link a page that explain how to use this?

Comment: ok, but like i said i cannot modify the parent form that way because the panels could be added dynamically and the panels could also have their own child.

Comment: If you can modify the form code to add the dynamic call to add the panels then you can add the delegate sub that handles the event. Otherwise your out of luck.

Comment: ok, thank you for your fast answers. Maybe i should look to make a panel "click through".

Comment: What is the purpose of this feature?

Answer (score 0):

On the child form

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports STAS_PLC_Link_Lib

Public Class ChildForm

    Public Event MyClick()
'.....rest of code
```

On the parent form

```
Public Class ParentForm

Private Sub GetSomeClick() Handles ChildFor.MyClick
        System.Console.WriteLine("test")
    End Sub
end Class
```