# Raise an event on another form

Tags: vb.net

I have two separated form(usercontrol A & B) in VB.Net. When a button clicked on formB, I want to an event raised on formA. How can do that? I searched stackoverflow.com and check several related solutions but they didn't work for me. I don't know what is the problem! Please help me. 
For Example I tried this code:

FormA:

```
Dim MyEditForm As New ucEmployeeTimeEdit
'some code for showing and preparing MyEditForm 
Private Sub GetSomeClick() Handles MyEditForm.MyClick
    System.Console.WriteLine("test")
End Sub
```

FormB:

```
Public Event MyClick()
Private Sub BtnDelet_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelet.Click
    RaiseEvent MyClick()
End Sub
```

Comment: Show us some code and perhaps we can help...

Comment: for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21564067/passing-event-to-the-parent-form

Comment: Great...how are **YOU** implementing that example?  We can't help you fix your code if we can't see it.

Comment: @Idle_Mind I edited my question by adding tried codes. Thanks for you attention.

Comment: *"I want to an event raised on formA"*. For the record, no you don't. You want an event raised in `formB` and **HANDLED** in `formA`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Idle_Mind answer is great, here's an alternative method with different advantages. (EDIT: I just noticed that he mentions this too, so you can consider this an elaboration on this subject)

If you keep FormB as a modal variable inside FormA, you can tell VB that you want to use it's events. Here's some skeleton code to show you:

```
Public Class FormA
    Private WithEvents myFormB As FormB

    'rest of the code for FormA
    'you can use FormB's events like this

    Private Sub GetSomeClicks() Handles myFormB.MyClick
        'code code code
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class FormB
    Public Event MyClick()
End Class
```

Have fun!

Comment: If you only ever want **ONE** instance of the form, this way is great.  If you need multiple forms and want to wire each of them to fire the same handler, then use `AddHandler`.

Answer (score 3):

Somewhere in the `some code` portion, you need to use [AddHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/addhandler-statement) to "wire up" that event:

```
Public Sub Foo()
    Dim MyEditForm As New ucEmployeeTimeEdit
    'some code for showing and preparing MyEditForm 
    AddHandler MyEditForm.MyClick, AddressOf GetSomeClick
End Sub

Private Sub GetSomeClick()
    System.Console.WriteLine("test")
End Sub
```

Note that `GetSomeClick()` does not have a "Handles" clause on the end.  This is because your instance of ucEmployeeTimeEdit was a **local** variable.

If you had declared it as [WithEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/withevents) at class level, then you could use the "Handles" clause (and consequently would no longer need the `AddHandler` call).